# Creating a zebra effect using listings

Tags: listings, color

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`lstlinebgrd` (`lstaddons` bundle)](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons)

Friends, consider the following example using the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output is as we expect:

[image: Hello World]

I was wondering if we could add something I know as *zebra effect* (pardon my possible misinterpretation of this term). I know this as a common style used in tables, where rows alternate colors, hence the name *zebra*. The previous example should look something like this:

[image: Hello Zebra]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I’m sorry that I can’t really help, but I googled “listings alternatin color“ and found a post in [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/St4Hp6ct_cA) with a solution for `fancyverb`

Comment: @Tobi interesting approach! I'm gonna take a look, probably we can come up with something similar for `listings`. =)

Comment: I had a look at listings and can’t find something similar to `\FancyVerbFormatLine`, sorry

Comment: I now released my solution as `lstlinebgrd` package on CTAN as part of the [`lstaddons`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) bundle.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following code is giving a zebra effect. See below for a description.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,numberstyle=\zebra{green!35}{yellow!35},numbers=left]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\bigskip

% If you want to make the bars shorter you need to use a `minipage` or similar environment:
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,numberstyle=\zebra{green!25}{white},numbers=left]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

My first idea was to use `backgroundcolor` with a conditional depending on the line number, but it seem only be used for boxing the whole listing. After studying the source code of `listings` a while to learn how to hack the line processing I came to the idea to (mis-)use the `numberstyle` for this. It is called with the line number register as argument and is typeset inside a `\llap` in a distance of `numbersep`. I just put a low-level command of `\colorbox` (`xcolor` package) called `\color@block` inside a `\rlap` to place the colored bars. This requires `numbers=left`. If you don't want lines numbers keep `\realnumberstyle` how it is, or redefine it otherwise.

If you only want one color you can use the following definition and `numberstyle=\zebra{<color>}`.

```
\newcommand{\zebra}[2]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#2}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
```

---

In the meantime I had a second look on the `listings` source code, this time to the `numbers` key. The following package hacks this key to inserts its own handler without interfering with the numbering like the code above. It then provides a set of new `listings` keys/options called `linebackground...`, to the set background color but also the height, depth, width, separation or even the drawing command.

You can set the color using `linebackgroundcolor=<some color code>` which can hold a conditional. The default background color is `-.`, i.e. the opposite (`-`) of the current foreground color (aliased as `.` by `xcolor`). The box drawing code follows after color code inside braces, so if not background is wanted (not even a white one) than the color code can simply gobble the box drawing code as an argument.

```
% lstlinebgrd.sty
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

% Patch line number key to call line background macro
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \def\lst@PlaceNumber{\lst@linebgrd}%
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\lst@linebgrd}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\lst@linebgrd}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}

% New keys
\lst@Key{linebackgroundcolor}{}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrdcolor{#1}%
}
\lst@Key{linebackgroundsep}{0pt}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrdsep{#1}%
}
\lst@Key{linebackgroundwidth}{\linewidth}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrdwidth{#1}%
}
\lst@Key{linebackgroundheight}{\ht\strutbox}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrdheight{#1}%
}
\lst@Key{linebackgrounddepth}{\dp\strutbox}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrddepth{#1}%
}
\lst@Key{linebackgroundcmd}{\color@block}{%
    \def\lst@linebgrdcmd{#1}%
}


% Line Background macro
\newcommand{\lst@linebgrd}{%
    \ifx\lst@linebgrdcolor\empty\else
    \rlap{%
        \lst@basicstyle
        \color{-.}% By default use the opposite (`-`) of the current color (`.`) as background
        \lst@linebgrdcolor{%
        \kern-\dimexpr\lst@linebgrdsep\relax%
        \lst@linebgrdcmd{\lst@linebgrdwidth}{\lst@linebgrdheight}{\lst@linebgrddepth}%
        }%
    }%
    \fi
}
```

#### Usage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{green}\fi}]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily\Large,linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{green}\else\color{yellow}\fi},linebackgroundsep=1em,linebackgroundwidth=18em]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny,linebackgroundcolor={\color{blue!\the\numexpr 5*\value{lstnumber}\relax}},linebackgroundheight=1.7ex,linebackgrounddepth=.4ex]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow Martin, that's a pretty impressive code! I thought about a conditional depending on the line number too, but I couldn't go any further. Your answer is highly technical and very didatic, thanks a million! Hats off to ya! =D

Comment: @Paulo: I just figured out a way to add this as normal `listings` settings. I will publish the code for that tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome! I'm very curious!

Comment: amazing code, I bow before your skills! In my first code sketch I was trying to get the current line number and check it, but I wasn't unable of finding it. Besides, I was tempted to hack the `basicstyle` key, but it happened to be only a big block for the whole listing. Again, your code is highly technical and didatic, thanks! BTW, I'm not sure if possible, but have you considered including this new package in the _TeX-SX_ initiave? I'd be great!

Comment: Really slick.  Can you update it to handle line breaks/wrapping as well?  I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @uosɐſ: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24046/2975 which addresses this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to integrate that other post's code with your nice lstlinebgrd package.  Doesn't any fix for wrapped lines belong in the package as a version 0.2?

Comment: @uosɐſ: That was the plan, but I didn't found time for it yet.

Comment: The goal of this is to have all the wrapped lines in the same color. This however always prefers the second color for wrapped lines :(

Comment: @Martin, `lstlinebgrd` does not work anymore with recent updated lstlisting package v1.7[2018/09/02] to highlight few lines of code. I tried your answer here and got the same error message as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451532/18678). Please fix it.

Comment: I'd like to kindly remind you that the latest CTAN version of this package is still broken.