# Test  if a number is in a comma separated range/list of numbers

Tags: tex-core, listings

Martin Scharrer posted a very elegant answer for the question ["Creating a zebra effect using listings"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/creating-a-zebra-effect-using-listings). I want to extend that code to highlight only lines given in a comma separated list. The motivations is that I want to highlight certain lines of fully functional C code inputed from a file without using any escape chars

That means that I need a command

```
\ifinrange{<num>}{<range>}{<TRUE>}{<FALSE>}% num>=0
```

where range `{-2,4,8-10, 15-}` is `{0,1,2,4,8,9,10,15,16,...}`

```
\ifinrange{ 0}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> TRUE
\ifinrange{ 3}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> FALSE
\ifinrange{ 4}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> TRUE
\ifinrange{ 9}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> TRUE    %% EDIT: changed 7 to 9
\ifinrange{11}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> FALSE
\ifinrange{20}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> TRUE
```

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}
\newcommand{\HighLight}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifinrange{\value{lstnumber}}{#2}{%
        \color{#1}%
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}}}{}%
    \endgroup}
\newcommand{\ifinrange}[4]{}%%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
                   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                   numberstyle=\HighLight{green!35}{-3,6},
                   numbers=left]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

must produce

[image]

Comment: I would name this question more after the `inline` macro required. The exact application is only secondary here.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: You are right. I have changed the title

Comment: `\ifinrange{ 7}{-2,4,8-10, 15-}{TRUE}{FALSE}  -> TRUE` should be FALSE instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a basic solution which works with your input. It might break on spaces at the wrong positions, so avoid them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}
\newcommand{\HighLight}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifinrange{\value{lstnumber}}{#2}{%
        \color{#1}%
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}}}{}%
    \endgroup}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcount\rangea
\newcount\rangeb

\newcommand\ifinrange[2]{%
    \global\let\inrange\@secondoftwo
    \foreach \range in {#2} {%
        \afterassignment\getrangeb
        \rangea=0\range\relax
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{ ( #1 >= \rangea) && (#1 <= \rangeb) }%
        \ifnum\result=1\relax
            \breakforeach
            \global\let\inrange\@firstoftwo
        \fi
    }%
    \inrange
}
\newcommand\getrangeb{%
    \@ifnextchar\relax
        {\rangeb=\rangea}%
        {\@getrangeb}%
}
\def\@getrangeb-#1\relax{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax
        \rangeb=100000%   \maxdimen is too large for pgfmath
    \else
        \rangeb=#1\relax
    \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
                   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                   numberstyle=\HighLight{green!35}{-3,6},
                   numbers=left]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I'd do also `\global\let\inrange\@secondoftwo`, to prevent save stack buildup.