# Highlighting a Chunk of Code within a lstlisting by specifying the line number

Tags: listings, highlighting, minted, animations

This question in somehow related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304315/highlighting-a-chunk-of-code-within-a-lstlisting but not exactly the same.

I want to make some slides with animation where one can see the execution of a program. The code is printed with `lstlisting`.

In order to make the code more readable, I want to highlight the line that is currently executed. The URL I show above has a solution where one modifies the code. Since I want to make animations, the code itself remains the same. Therefore it would be useful that I can just specify the line number and LaTeX will do the rest.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Does the code work for you?

Comment: Have a look at [Test if a number is in a comma separated range/list of numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19000/test-if-a-number-is-in-a-comma-separated-range-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comment you want to use `pygmentize`. A solution with `listings` is provided here: [highlight lines in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58540/highlight-lines-in-listings/58543#58543)

The package `minted` and `verbments` are using the parser `pygmentize` (see: [minted vs. texments vs. verbments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/minted-vs-texments-vs-verbments)). I am using `verbments` here. Both packages require the package `fancyvrb` to print the contents. So you can manipulate some commands of `fancyvrb` without influencing the output of `pygmentize`.

In the example below I provide two new keys:

- `bgrlinenbr` - accepts a comma list representing the line numbers. These lines will be highlighted by the given color of `bgrlineclr`
- `bgrlineclr` - defines the background color of the highlighted line.

Here the result and code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{verbments}
\makeatletter

\def\highlightedlines{}
\def\highlightedcolor{white}
\define@cmdkey{pyglist}[pl@]{bgrlinenbr}{\def\highlightedlines{#1}}%number
\define@cmdkey{pyglist}[pl@]{bgrlineclr}{\def\highlightedcolor{#1}}%color
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \FancyVerbFormatLine { m }
{
 \clist_if_in:NVTF  \highlightedlines  { \the\value{FancyVerbLine} }
   { 
    \colorbox{\highlightedcolor}{#1}
  }
  {
     #1
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{pyglist}[language=c,numbers=right,bgrlinenbr={1,2,4},bgrlineclr=red!20]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't count `minted` out just yet.  I've been communicating with Konrad Rudolph since learning that [minted is no longer maintained](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/minted-vs-texments-vs-verbments/102940#102940), and am planning to maintain `minted` in the future.

Comment: @G.Poore: I had the same idea as I read his answer ;-)

Comment: Maybe we can get several people working on `minted`.

Comment: @G.Poore: Will you provide a github repository?

Comment: It will be at https://github.com/gpoore/minted. The issue tracking is still at https://code.google.com/p/minted/ for the moment, but I'll probably transition that to GitHub as well.