# Add key for new Listings environment

Tags: listings, key-value

I'm trying to add a new key to a custom `listings` environment. I have tried to modify [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31383/highlighting-line-ranges-in-listings).

My problem is that the value I am attempting to pass through in the document for the key does not seem to be used.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{pagewidth}{\linewidth}{\def\LSTwidth{#1}}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
\noindent
\minipage{\LSTwidth}
\lstset{#1}
}
{\endminipage}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{mylisting}[pagewidth=0.5\linewidth, frame=lrtb]
NOT IMPORTANT NOT IMPORTANT
NOT IMPORTANT NOT IMPORTANT
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line `\lstset{#1}` *before* the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{pagewidth}{\linewidth}{\def\LSTwidth{#1}}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
\noindent
\lstset{#1}
\minipage{\LSTwidth}
}
{\endminipage}

\begin{document}

\hrulefill

\centering
\begin{mylisting}[pagewidth=0.5\linewidth, frame=lrtb]
NOT IMPORTANT NOT IMPORTANT
NOT IMPORTANT NOT IMPORTANT
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added a horizontal rule just for visualization purposes.

By the way, `listings` already has a `linewidth` key with a similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I have a very superficial understanding of how this works. Is the key only available after #1 is expanded?

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome. As you had it, `minipage` was not aware of the change to its width, because the change was being made after the initial value (`\linewidth`) had been used as the width for the `minipage`.