# Multiplication with dimexpr?

Tags: calculations

(This post bases on: [lstaddons: Dynamic linewidth calculation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70803/lstaddons-dynamic-linewidth-calculation/70816#70816))

Hey everyone,
is there a way to do this with a multiplication instead of two additions?

```
\dimexpr\linewidth+\lst@linebgrdsep+\lst@linebgrdsep\relax
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `\lst@linebgrdsep` is a register then:

```
\dimexpr\linewidth + 2\lst@linebgrdsep \relax
```

Hint: Real numbers are also possible.

Otherwise:

```
\dimexpr\linewidth + (\lst@linebgrdsep)*2 \relax
```

Note, the first factor is the length value, the integer factors follows afterwards in the product. This is limited to integer numbers.

Real numbers can be supported by wrapping the macro `\lst@linebgrdsep` in `\dimexpr`.

```
\dimexpr\linewidth + 1.5\dimexpr\lst@linebgrdsep\relax \relax
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the definition of `\lst@linebgrdsep`, so I define it here.

```
\newdimen\lst@linebgrdsep
\lst@linebgrdsep.5\textwidth
\edef\x{\the\dimexpr\linewidth+\lst@linebgrdsep*2\relax}
\show\x
```