# dimexpr: multiplication with constant real factor from macro

Tags: macros, calculations, dimension-expressions

I want to multiply a constant from a macro with a deimension using `dimexpr`.
When using real numbers the decimal point and the decimal digits are typeset behind the result and the result is a mutliplication with the floor value of the constant used.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
  \def\const{1.9}
  \noindent
  \the\dimexpr \linewidth*\const\relax \newline
  \the\dimexpr \linewidth*\numexpr\const\relax\relax \newline
  \the\linewidth
\end{document}
```

The second multiplication is an attempt to use the suggestion from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70823/19326), to wrap the macro in a sub expression

Comment: I've answered, but the answer you link to does include more-or-less the same points. This question therefore might be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @JosephWright: just mark it as a duplicate, I don't mind. I overlooked it since I skimmed the awnser and read the bottom part, starting `Real numbers can be supported by ...` thats why I wondered where I went wrong. I am propably used by `pgf`s math capabilities.

Comment: Looking again I think probably not a dupe: the _questions_ have a different focus (the other one on what to do to avoid repeated addition, here about the syntax of multiplication).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\dimexpr` doesn't allow arbitrary calculations: you need to have things in the correct form. In particular, if you want to multiply a dimension by a decimal then you need to use the form

```
<multiple><dimension>
```

So you example will work with

```
\the\dimexpr\const\linewidth\relax
```

while the format

```
\the\dimexpr\linewidth*\const\relax
```

can only be used if `\const` is an integer.

(The linked answer [Multiplication with dimexpr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70819/multiplication-with-dimexpr/70823#70823) does mention this limitation.)