# Moving a TikZ drawn `mdframed` `frametitle` box vertically by a real amount?

Tags: boxes, mdframed, lengths, dimension-expressions

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} % noteboxes, boxes, etc.
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\definebox}[2]{%
    \newcounter{#1}
    \newenvironment{#1}[1][]{%
        \stepcounter{#1}%
        \mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[]
                \node[rectangle,fill=white]
                {\strut \MakeUppercase#1~\csname the #1\endcsname\ifstrempty{##1}{}{:~##1}};}}%
        \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=1pt,linecolor=#2,%
            linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
            frametitleaboveskip={\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-1\relax},}%
        \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
        }{\end{mdframed}}%
}

\definebox{definition}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{Cats}
        Warm kitty, sweet kitty, little ball of fur. Warm kitty, sweet kitty, purr, purr, purr.

    \begin{definition}[Kitten.]
        A kitten is a baby cat.
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

It produces this as output:

[image]

If I change `frametitleaboveskip={\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-1\relax}` to `frametitleaboveskip={\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-2\relax}`, the output will look like:

[image]

But if change it to `frametitleaboveskip={\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-1.99\relax}`, the output seems to be the same as `frametitleaboveskip={\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-1\relax}` except for a mysterious `pt` that appears:

[image]

How can I move the `frametitle` box up by a real amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126359/47927

So, in short, you have to reorder

```
\dimexpr (\ht\strutbox)*-1.99\relax
```

to

```
\dimexpr -1.99\ht\strutbox\relax
```