# Alternate text style for odd and even line

Tags: listings

I want to make someting like the lstlinebgrd package to creating a zebra effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%If not an error occurs
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{green}\fi}]
    First line
    Second line
    Third line
    Fourth line
\end{lstlisting}
```

but alternate text style for odd and even line, like this non-working code:
note the **basicstyle={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\it\fi}**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%If not an error occurs
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\it\fi},linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{green}\fi}]
    First line : normalfont
    Second line : italic
    Third line : normal font
    Fourth line : italic
\end{lstlisting}
```

I have tried to modify the code from : [Creating a zebra effect using listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/creating-a-zebra-effect-using-listings) (who led to the package lstlinebgrd) without succes.

I know the listing package, nor the package lstlinebgrd are conceive for that. 
My latexfuu is not enough to hack a solution. 
Maybe you can help me, or give me a direction? An other package maybe.
The solution don't have to be for code but for text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather then use of `basicstyle` which  will be applied on all listing code you can modify `identifierstyle`, `commentstyle`, `stringstyle`, `keywordstyle` like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%If not an error occurs

\def\oddtest{\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\normalfont\else\itshape\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
    identifierstyle=\oddtest,
    commentstyle=\oddtest,
    stringstyle=\oddtest,
    keywordstyle=\oddtest,
    linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{green}\fi}]
    First line : normalfont     % comment
    Second line : italic        % comment
    Third line : normal font
    Fourth line : italic
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]