# change background color for some lines inside a `listings` block

Tags: color, listings

I need to change background color for some lines inside a `listings` block. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\add}{\makebox[0pt]{\color{green}\rule[-1ex]{\paperwidth}{3ex}}} 

\begin{document}

\lstset{ %
  escapechar=|,
  language=Python                       % the language of the code
}

\begin{lstlisting}

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        x = 8
        x = 9

        |\add|# some additions
        |\add|x = 10
        |\add|if True:
        |\add|    x = 11

        x = 20
        x = 21

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

the problem is that instead of a single green block, it appears a "cebra" pattern with one green block for each line:

[image]

Some suggestions about how to fix this issue?

(I know there are several similar questions, but none of the found answers seems applicable).

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/creating-a-zebra-effect-using-listings

Comment: @Ignasi: Interesting, but I do not see how to apply to this case.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui If you found an adequate answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`fvextra`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package (`fvextra` – Extensions and patches for fancyvrb), specifically, the `highlightlines` feature.
Note that you may also have to use the line numbering option in order to deduce which are the lines that you want to highlight. Of course, you can switch this option off afterwards.

Here is your MWE (mind the capital V in `Verbatim`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left, highlightlines=12-15]

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

class Foo:
def __init__(self):
x = 8
x = 9

# some additions
x = 10
if True:
  x = 11

x = 20
x = 21

\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

**PS:** for compatible (Python) syntax colouring you might want to try the [`pygments`](http://pygments.org/) package from the same author. It is basically a Python script that can also output LaTeX code. Many programing languages are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Based on his answer to [Creating a zebra effect using listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/creating-a-zebra-effect-using-listings), Martin Scharrer wrote [`lstlinebgrd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lstlinebgrd) package. It helps to control background lines aspect for `lstlistings` environments.

In this particular case, the option `linebackgroundcolor` is enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\begin{document}

\lstset{ %
  escapechar=|,
  language=Python                       % the language of the code
}

\begin{lstlisting}[
        linebackgroundcolor={%
        \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>11
            \ifnum\value{lstnumber}<16
                \color{green!35}
            \fi
        \fi},
]

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        x = 8
        x = 9

        # some additions
        x = 10
        if True:
            x = 11

        x = 20
        x = 21

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interesting approach. But the original code is the result of apply a "diff" over the two sources. Control the block of lines using its line number is not practical.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Hasta ahí no llego ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Another question has been created, this time including the problem of overstrike and showing more tests done. Could be this one reaches the objective (I can not delete this one because there are already answers).