# Add colored background to listing with colored words

Tags: listings, color

I wish to (manually) add a colored background to particular lines in a `lstlisting`. There are quite a few answers already, which use `realboxes` package or a colorbox. However, the color I defined does not show up, and it removes the letter color that I set up.  Here's a minimum working example:

```
% annotation background colors
\definecolor{blueannoback}{RGB}{51,51,255} % use xcolor package
\definecolor{greenannoback}{RGB}{230,244,214}

\begin{lstfloat}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={\%*}{*),morecomment=[l][\textcolor{BurntOrange}]{@}]}
%*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Anno1}*)
%*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@Anno2}*)
@Anno3
public void MyClass {}
\end{lstlisting}\end{lstfloat}
```

The idea is that @Anno1, @Anno2 and @Anno3 have the text color `BurntOrange` (because the line starts with @). Additionally, @Anno1 should have a light blue background (that ideally spans just around the code, not the entire line), and @Anno2 should have a green background.

The background colors are correct. However, the text of @Anno1 and @Anno2 are no longer `BurntOrange`, presumably because the line no longer starts with @.

Additionally, the annotation text is slightly shifted to the right (which I can live with, but would be nice to fix this as well).

So how do I preserve the text color, while adding the background color?

Comment: Is it a duplicat of [change background color for some lines inside a `listings` block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371424/124842)?

Comment: @Bobyandbob I saw that answer before I asked this question but I deemed it unsatisfactory.  It produces an overly big static rectangle, while I only wanted the background to wrap around the text.  I've come up with a solution in the meantime, which I will post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## My solution

### (Optional) Define custom colors

I first created some custom colors in `mysettings.sty`.

```
% annotation background colors
\definecolor{blueannoback}{RGB}{234,242,250}
\definecolor{greenannoback}{RGB}{230,244,214}
```

My `main.tex` file includes the following packages:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mysettings}
```

### Custom listing style

Next I define a custom style for each programming language of my choice. In this example I define a custom language which is based on Java.

The custom Java language allows me to color the font of my annotations automatically:

```
% Define custom Java language
\lstdefinelanguage{custom-java}{
    ...,
    morecomment=[l][\textcolor{BurntOrange}]{@}
}
```

The custom listing style provides a custom way to specify `escapeinside` in order to use LateX commands inside my listing, which I will need:

```
\lstdefinestyle{my-java-style}{
    language=custom-java,
    ...,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}
```

### The listing

I then use a `colorbox` to wrap the text in a background with the color of my choosing.  The text needs to be escaped so that LateX code may be executed inside the listing.  Note that this overrides the **BurntOrange** font color I had defined for lines that start with `@`.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=my-java-style, otherkeywords={this}]
%*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Entity}*)
%*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Table(name="CourseCredits")}*)
%*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@Function}*)
public class CourseCredit %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{implements Serializable}*) {
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Id}*)
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Column(name="Course")}*)
    %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@ArgumentType(value=1, typeName="Course")}*)
    private String course;
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Column(name="Credits")}*)
    %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@FunctionValue("Credits")}*)
    private int credits;

    public %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{CourseCredit()}*){
    }

    public %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{CourseCredit(String course, int credits)}*){
        this.course = course;
        this.credits = credits;
    }
}\end{lstlisting}
```

### Result

[image]

## Full code for minimal working example

Here's the full code to reproduce the above image.  I tried to keep it compact.

`mysettings.sty`

```
% Colors
\definecolor{javapurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\definecolor{blueannoback}{RGB}{234,242,250}
\definecolor{greenannoback}{RGB}{230,244,214}

% Define language
\lstdefinelanguage{my-java}{
    keywords={private,public,class,this}
}

% define style
\lstdefinestyle{my-java-style}{
    language=my-java,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,   
    captionpos=b,                  
    alsoletter={.},         
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},       
    extendedchars=true,          
    frame=tb,                     
    keepspaces=true,   
    keywordstyle=\color{javapurple}\bfseries,  
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    tabsize=4
}
```

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mysettings} % my .sty file

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=my-java-style,otherkeywords={this}]
%*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Entity}*)
%*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Table(name="CourseCredits")}*)
%*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@Function}*)
public class CourseCredit %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{implements Serializable}*) {
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Id}*)
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Column(name="Course")}*)
    %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@ArgumentType(value=1, typeName="Course")}*)
    private String course;
    %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{@Column(name="Credits")}*)
    %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{@FunctionValue("Credits")}*)
    private int credits;

    public %*\colorbox{blueannoback}{CourseCredit()}*){
    }

    public %*\colorbox{greenannoback}{CourseCredit(String course, int credits)}*){
        this.course = course;
        this.credits = credits;
    }
}\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```