# How can I add code highlighting for listings with different colour lines?

Tags: listings, highlighting, syntax-highlighting

How can I create a listing design in LaTeX, with numbers on the left, and each line separated with colours like in the picture? I could not find such listing style for LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18969/134144 and the resulting package lstlinebgrd should come in handy for this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, for alternating line background colors the `lstlinebgrd` package can be used (see also [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451532/recent-issues-with-lstlinebgrd-package-with-listings-after-the-latters-updates)). For the line numbers' background color we can use an extra wide frame only on the left side of the listing, for the separator rule we can combine the frame separator with the fill color.

We use the following options to adjust the layout (I think the rest is self-explaning):

- `framexleftmargin` indents the code a bit, `linebackgroundsep` and `linebackgroundwidth` compensate the background coloring for this indentation.
- `framesep` sets a small gap between the code and the left frame which is filled by `fillcolor`.
- `framerule` is the width of the left frame, `rulecolor` is its color and `numbersep` is the distance of the line numbers from the right side of the frame plus gap. There's an extra macro `\numberstyle` for styling the line numbers itself to test for numbers smaller than ten and pad them with a leading zero if necessary.
- `xleftmargin` pushes the whole listings to the right by the width of the frame, the gap and the indentation such that the line numbers aren't printed in the left margin.

Full example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily\small,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\numberstyle,
    linebackgroundcolor=\linebgstyle,
    frame=l,
    % code indentation
    framexleftmargin=0.5em,
    linebackgroundsep=0.5em,
    linebackgroundwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth+0.5em\relax,
    % separation rule
    framesep=3pt,
    fillcolor=\color{green!80!black},
    % numbers background
    framerule=4em,
    numbersep=\dimexpr 1.5em+3pt\relax,
    rulecolor=\color{lightgray!50!white},
    % don't put numbers into margin
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr 4em+3pt+0.5em\relax,
}
\newcommand\linebgstyle{%
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{white}%
    \else
        \color{lightgray!10!white}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand\numberstyle[1]{%
    \small\ttfamily
    \color{gray!60!black}%
    \ifnum#1<10 0\else\fi
    #1.%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

% example code from http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/DRIVER.vhd
\begin{lstlisting}
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Driver is
port(   x: in std_logic;
    F: out std_logic
);
end Driver;  

architecture behv1 of Driver is
begin

    process(x)
    begin
        -- compare to truth table
        if (x='1') then
            F <= '1';
        else
            F <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end behv1;

architecture behv2 of Driver is 
begin 

    F <= x; 

end behv2; 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: It only works if I remove the \usepackage{lstlinebgrd}. And also it is not aligned on the left of the page which makes the code get out of the page. Thanks for the try though !